# How to create a Net Core Middleware to validate a route parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware, asp.net-core-routing, asp.net-core-7.0

Using Net Core 7 I have Razor Pages with a `culture` route parameter:

```
@page "/{culture:validculture}/about"
```

I created a custom route constraint to check if `culture` has a valid value.

When the `culture` value is invalid I am redirected to a 404 error page.

```
public class CultureRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint {

    private readonly RequestLocalizationOptions _options;

  public CultureRouteConstraint(IOptionsSnapshot<RequestLocalizationOptions> options) {

        _options = options.Value;

  } 

  public Boolean Match(HttpContext? httpContext, IRouter? route, String routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {
    
    String? culture = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    List<String>? cultures = _options.SupportedCultures?.Select(x => x.TwoLetterISOLanguageName).ToList();

    if (culture != null && cultures != null)
      return cultures.Contains(culture, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

  }

}
```

This works great if I hardcode de valid cultures, e.g:

```
List<String>? cultures = new() { "en", "pt" };
```

But if I inject `RequestLocalizationOptions` I get the error:

```
RouteCreationException: An error occurred while trying to create an instance of 'CultureRouteConstraint'.
```

Maybe I need to use a Middleware for this? How can I do this?

Comment: Did you register the IOptionsSnapshot<RequestLocalizationOptions> with the DI container?

Comment: Yes, I have:`builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>)`... I also tried to inject it using `Options<RequestLocalizationOptions>` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because IOptionsSnapshot Is registered as Scoped and therefore can't be injected into a Singleton service.

You could try with IOptions (Not Options<>)instead If you don't have to update the options for different request),For Example,I tried as below and it works well in my case:

In program.cs:

```
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opts =>
{
    var supportedcultures = new List<CultureInfo>()
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("zh-CN")
    };
    opts.SupportedCultures = supportedcultures;
    opts.SupportedUICultures= supportedcultures;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddRouting(options =>
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("validculture", typeof(CultureRouteConstraint)));



var app = builder.Build();
```

The constraint:

```
public class CultureRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {



       private readonly RequestLocalizationOptions _options;



       public CultureRouteConstraint(IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> options)
        {



           _options = options.Value;



       }



       public Boolean Match(HttpContext? httpContext, IRouter? route, String routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {



           String? culture = Convert.ToString(values["culture"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);



           List<String>? cultures = _options.SupportedCultures?.Select(x => x.TwoLetterISOLanguageName).ToList();



           if (culture != null && cultures != null)
                return cultures.Contains(culture, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            else
                return false;



       }



   }
```

The Result:

[image]

You could also check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#options-interfaces) related

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using DI to inject the RequestLocalizationOptions into your CultureRouteConstraint class. However, the IRouteConstraint interface does not support DI, so you cannot inject dependencies into it directly.

One option you could consider is using a middleware to handle the routing constraint. The middleware could use DI to inject the RequestLocalizationOptions and then check the culture value before passing control to the appropriate Razor page.

Here's an example of what this might look like:

```
public class CultureMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly RequestLocalizationOptions _options;

    public CultureMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptionsSnapshot<RequestLocalizationOptions> options)
    {
        _next = next;
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Check the culture value
        string culture = context.Request.RouteValues["culture"].ToString();
        if (!_options.SupportedCultures.Select(x => x.TwoLetterISOLanguageName).Contains(culture, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            // Redirect to a 404 page if the culture value is invalid
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return;
        }

        // If the culture value is valid, pass control to the next middleware
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will then be checked for all requests which is probably not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you cannot use a DI constructor when working with implementations of `IRouteConstraint`, but you have the `HttpContext` in your `Match` method. So, you can resolve the `IOptionsSnapshot` from there. This should work:

```
var opts = ctx
    .RequestServices
    .GetService<IOptionsSnapshot<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
```